# Injective function for $F^n\rightarrow F^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ and $Y$ are $F$-linear and $\dim_FX=n$ and $\dim_FY=m$.
If $n\leq m$, does there exist an $F$-linear injective function $f:X\rightarrow Y$?
Well of course, but how do i notate that?

$$f\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots\\x_n\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

And am I right that this is from $F^n\to F^m$?

Note: for me it is not clear wether $x_i$ is element of Y or not, should i instead map $x_i \to y_i$?

Also, does $n\leq m$ imply that at least $n$ is finite?

Comment: The notation seems to imply that both $m$ and $n$ are finite, though the statement holds in the infinite case as well, as YoTengoUnLCD's answer illustrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a basis of $X$. Let $\{y_i\}_i$ be a basis of $Y$.

Prove that the unique linear transformation that sends $x_i\mapsto y_i$ is an injection (further hint, use that $\{y_i\}$ is a basis of $Y$).

Regarding you questions: Yes, $x_i$ may not be an element of $Y$, so it makes little sense to use it as such.

Also, we could have $n\leq m$ even when $n$ is not finite (we could have $n=\aleph_0,\, m=\mathfrak c$).

---

The transformation is indeed $T\,x_i=y_i$. It's a basic theorem in linear algebra that a linear transformation is completely determined by its action on a basis (that's why we can talk about **the** linear transformation here).

Let $\{y_i\}$ be as defined above. Let $v_1,v_2\in X$ and suppose $T \,v_1=T\, v_2$. We know that $v_1=\sum c_i x_i$ and $v_2=\sum k_i x_i$ for some $c_i,k_i$.

From linearity, it follows that $T \, v_1 = \sum c_i y_i$ and $T\, v_2=\sum k_i y_i$.

Here we use that $\{y_i\}$ is a basis, this gives us that the representation of any vector $u$ as a sum $\sum r_i y_i$ has a unique combination of $r_i$'s, so we get that $c_i=k_i$ and finally, $v_1=v_2$, thus $T$ is injective.

Comment: Let $n\leq m$.
Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a Basis of $X$. Let $\{y_i\}_i$ be a Basis of $Y$.
The unique linear transformation $t$, that sends $x_i\mapsto y_i$ is an injection.
Since $\{y_i\}_i$ is a basis of $Y$ , $\{y_i\}_i\subseteq Y$ holds.\\
From 2.2.1(college-script) we know:
For every linear independant set $A\subseteq X$, therefore $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ too, the set $t(A)\subseteq Y$, that means also for $\{y_i\}_i$, is linear independant$\iff$ $t$ is injectiv.

But damn, what how does $t$ look like?

Something like this?
$t(x_i)=y_i$, where $i=1,\cdots,n$.

Comment: @saturatedexpo I'll expand my answer a bit.

Comment: @saturatedexpo I updated the post giving a more explicit answer.

Comment: hi, why is the notation $Tx$ and not $T(x)$? (or, what does it mean to not have a bracket there)

Comment: @saturatedexpo Oh, it's just a convention used when $T$ is a linear transformation, this is because linear transformations can often be written as matrices (in the sense that if $T(x)$ is a linear transformation, there exists a matrix $A$ such that $T(x) = A\, x$). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the dimensions, assume that $A=\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ and $B=\{u_1,\cdots, u_m\}$ are the basis of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Now, for each $x\in X$, we know that there are $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n$ such that $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iv_i$. So, it is enough to define $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iu_i$.

It is simple to show that it is an injection.

This way, you can be sure that the image of $f$ is subset of $Y$.